# How to make the screen in linux live in php?

Tags: php, html, screen, ssh2

```
<?php
    $ssh2 = new ogcp_ssh2();
    if($ssh2->ConnectwAuth($serverinfo["MachIP"],(int)$serverinfo["MachPort"],$serverinfo["MachUser"],$serverinfo["MachPass"])) {
        $icerik = stream_get_contents($ssh2->Exec('cd '.$serverinfo["ServerPath"].'; tail -15 screenlog.0'));
    } else {
        $icerik = "";
    }
    if(isset($_POST["sbmt"], $_POST["cmdd"])) {
        $_POST["cmdd"] = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST["cmdd"])));
        $durum = false;
        $bad_commands = array(
        "screen","-dr","-X","quit","shutdown","exit",";","sv_downloadurl","hostname","rcon_password","sv_contact","sv_maxrate","sv_minrate","sv_maxupdaterate","sv_minupdaterate","sys_ticrate","fps_max","fps_modem"
        );
        for($i=0; $i < count($bad_commands); $i++) {
            if(strpos($_POST["cmdd"],$bad_commands[$i]) !== false) { $durum = true; break; }
        }
        $komut = "screen -S {$serverinfo["Screen"]} -X -p0 eval \"stuff '{$_POST["cmdd"]}'^m\"";
        if(!$durum) {
            $shell = @$ssh2->Exec($komut);
        } else {
            $shell = false;
        }
        if($shell != false) {
            print('<div class="alert success"><span class="hide">×</span><strong>Başarılı!</strong> '.$_POST["cmdd"].' komutu gonderildi!</div>');
            $icerik = stream_get_contents(@$ssh2->Exec('cd '.$serverinfo["ServerPath"].'; tail -15 screenlog.0'));
        } else {
            print('<div class="alert error"><span class="hide">×</span><strong>Başarısız!</strong> '.$_POST["cmdd"].' komutu gonderilemedi!</div>');
        }
    }
?>
```

How can I make the screen managers live? I have provided the html and php codes above, I would appreciate if you could help :)

Comment: Sending the output of a single (SSH) command isn't that hard, but maintaining a session is where it gets complicated. My recommend would be to look at an existing solution. On the [xterm](https://xtermjs.org/) site, if you search for "SSH" you'll find a bunch of existing solutions.

Comment: Is there a way to screen? I'm installing xterm as + I get an error on my server

Comment: "Is there a way to screen?" - I don't know what that means

Comment: wouldn't it be live with screen?

Comment: You mean "screen" the terminal emulation utility? Does it support emulating over HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: ajax js live using linux display